# How can I read a barcode from a browser

Tags: c#, barcode

Is it possible to read a barcode from mobile browser? I need to make a mobile web page that takes as input a scanned tag of an item from a store. It also needs to support mobile apps later on. I am developing the website in .Net. I need the barcode to be read through the camera of the phone.

I am developing the website in C#. Not sure if this adds any limitations. 
Do you know any library for that?

Comment: [WhatHaveYouTried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Well, I haven't found anything so far and that is why I asked

Comment: How does it take a scanned tag? Upload a pic?

Comment: I am open to suggestions. The only limitation is to be easy for the user and to be without additional devices.

Comment: Not sure where C# comes from in this question - "how to read image from camera in mobile browser" does not seem to involve any C# code...

Comment: cos if it takes just a pic and then it "reads" it on the server, then it matters

Answer (score 4):

depends on what approach you want to take.....

simplest approach is to get a barcode reader and put it into "keyboard wedge" mode and scan in stuff that way, so it basically looks like someone typing in things

More complicated,  there's libs out there that use the webcam as a barcode reader and you can access it via javascript

Comment: Yes, I want to read it from the camera, but the only thing I found is through flash and I dont thing it is really good for mobile devices

Comment: there's libs that use  "getUserMedia" which is part of HTML5,  not everything supports it though, but there are a number of browsers that do, including mobile ones

Comment: can you recommend me any lib? This sounds like to do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question Teddy.  If I understand correctly, you are merely using C# ASP.NET on the server side, not on the client-side. If you wanted to consider Silverlight you could have a look at Greg Bray's C# Silverlight port of ZXing.  However, from what I understand from your comment in Keith's reply, this is not what you want to do. (Silverlight is very similar to Flash, which you reject, and less widely supported on mobile devices.)

Taking Flash and Silverlight out of the picture, you have two problems to tackle, possibly using different technologies:

1. Get the browser to interface to the device's camera and capture an image.  If you do not want to use Flash (or Silverlight), you will have to rely on functionality that is slowly finding its way in new browsers, including mobile browsers.   Eric Bibelman's blog is a good starting point: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/
2. You need to "read" the barcodes in the image.  There are two obvious options:

   A. Use javascript. (This is promising but I have not tried the available solutions and have my doubts about how far beyond a basic proof-of-concept functionality they will go.)  See for example Tobias Schneider's gist: https://gist.github.com/421369

   B. Post the image back to your server-side C# ASP.NET code and handle barcode recognition there.  You will then be able to use C# libraries, including a ZXing port.  (Or you could have a dedicated server using a different technology (e.g. Java) if you feel that opens the possibility to use better barcode recognition options.)

To be honest, I would first consider creating mobile apps using native interfaces and libraries for image capturing and barcode recognition and re-using my web-site work by embedding a web-browser control in the app. Doing this in Android, using ZXing, took me less than an hour and I think I would not have had too many obstacles with either iPhone or Windows Phone if I wanted to port the app to those platforms.